# Obtain average of fire base function, Find the average of the desired nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to average the fields I want from a database in Realtime Database and put them on another node

```
exports.taverage = functions.database.ref('/User/tsetUser/monthQuit/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        return admin.database().ref('/User/tsetUser/monthQuit/{pushId}/quitTime').once('value')
            .then(function(snapshot) {
                let sum=0;
                snapshot.forEach(child => {
                    sum = sum + child.val();
                })
                let avg = sum / snapshot.numChildren();

                return admin.database().ref('/User/tsetUser/inform/standardQuit').set(avg);
            });
    });
```

Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZyoY.png)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `.numChildren()` should actually be `.getChildrenCount()` as stated [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()).

Also, consider revising your code to account for the "divide by zero" case by doing something like the following:

```
functions.database.ref('/User/tsetUser/monthQuit/{pushId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return admin.database().ref('/User/tsetUser/monthQuit/{pushId}/quitTime').once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {

        /* Get children could via getChildrenCount() */
        let divisor = snapshot.getChildrenCount();

        /* Ensure divisor is greater than zero to avoid
        divide by zero case */
        if(divisor > 0) {

            let sum=0;

            snapshot.forEach(child => {
                sum = sum + child.val();
            })
            let avg = sum / divisor;

            return admin.database().ref('/User/tsetUser/inform/standardQuit').set(avg);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Error: The function was not deployed properly.
It was a code to get average of several quitTime in the attached image and put it in standardQuit.